# Convergence of $\sum q^{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$ with root test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0<q<1$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ $a_{n}=q^{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$.
Prove with the root test that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges.

I know I have to show that $\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}<q<1$ for some $n>N$, but it when I do this: $\sqrt[n]{q^{n+(-1)^{n+1}}}=q\cdot\sqrt[n]{q^{(-1)^{n+1}}}<1\cdot\sqrt[n]{q^{(-1)^{n+1}}}$ I can't say that it's smaller than $q$, because $q^{-1}$ will be greater than $1$ when $n$ is even. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to show that $ \sqrt[n]{a_n} < q < 1 $, you just need to show that $ \sqrt[n]{a_n} < p < 1 $ for some $ p < 1 $ that's not necessarily equal to $ q $. Can you finish the proof now?